# Why am I getting this "recursion depth" error message?

Tags: warning-messages, recursion

I am simply trying to use this command

```
p[1,2][1]/.{p[x_,y_][m_]:>pp[x,y][m]}
```

and I'm getting an error message

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
```

What am I doing that I shouldn't be?

Comment: Does `p` have any other definitions attached to it? As currently states this evaluates just fine for me in _Mathematica_ 10.2.

Comment: I didn't explicitly define p or pp elsewhere, but clearing both of their values fixed the problem for me. Do you know why this may have happened?

Comment: It's difficult to say. Perhaps it inadvertently got a value somewhere in your code (e.g. a `=` instead of a `==` somewhere).